# How to wrap up an independent blender application with customized UI for clients who do not need to install blender?

Tags: rendering, export, customization

Suppose I create an blender application in blender: a default block with block parameter buttons from pressing "N" on the keyboard, as shown in Figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xe5r.png). 
[image: A default block with block parameter buttons within Blender]

```
           Figure 1
```

So, users can change the parameters for different block views.

How can I wrap up the application with those parameter buttons only as a package (say, exe or msi or some other file) as shown in Figure 2
[image: A default block with block parameter buttons ONLY]

```
           Figure 2
```

for end users who don't need to install Blender. The end users just simply install the application, run it and get into the customized UI (Figure 2).

I have googled the web for it but no luck. Probably I used wrong keywords for googling.

Any suggestions?

Thank you very much in advance.

ouyang

Answer (score 4):

This is possible without any significant modifications.

- Download blender (the zipfile version)
- Add your own `2.72/config/startup.blend, userpref.blend`
  (depending on your configuration these files may have to be copied out of your personal settings into a directory relative to `blender.exe`
  see: https://www.blender.org/manual/installing_blender/directorylayout.html)
- modify `startup.blend` so the view is organized as you like (you can match the view you've created fairly easily).
- Any other runtime customizations you can add to a **Python** script in a text block (enable register, so it loads on startup).

You may also want to:

- Disable the splash screen: Preferences -> Interface -> Show Splash
- Rename `blender.exe`
- Change the icon (shouldn't be so hard with a recourse editor, you could also make a custom build).

Comment: Ideasman42, thanks for your help. I will try it and see what I can do.    ouyang